# Django Form Inputs Won't Show Up - Only See Submit Button

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm playing around with the forms framework, but the inputfields for my form will not show. I can only see the submit button.

forms.py

```
from django import forms

class NameForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(label='Enter your name', max_length=100)
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Enter your email', max_length=100)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,
from .forms import NameForm

def get_name(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NameForm(request.POST)
    else:
        form = NameForm()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})
```

index.html

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The responding html, when showed in my browser is the following:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="pSzpDAHu89XC8Re0aDYMOETDS30l3HozZWlL4fF0LljYkrXFCWIiOYCzYwOWtqjk">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I hope you are able to help or point me in some direction.

Comment: Make sure that your url-set is actually calling this view.

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to call`'get_name()` in urls.py. The form is now rendering after adding this line `path('', views.get_name, name='form'),` to the urlpattern in urls.py.